# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecs_logging' in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, modulenotfounderror

I'm working with an API which is made with fastapi. One of the packges required is ecs_logging. I have it installed in the enviroment, moreover I can even import it in the console. However at the time to run in the terminal the API it throws me that error. The place where the console and the terminal are been executed is the same.
What I am missing?
Thanks for your time.

I have try to install the package, and checked the directory not only where the package is installed but also where the API is running.

Comment: Is PyCharm using the same python environment that you installed the package in? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html